# Is there an input type that automatically ends after a certain number of characters has been entered?

Tags: c++, input, console-application

I am currently creating a console/text based version of Alchemy for my Data Structures class and am interested in limiting input during each 'turn' phase, but I can't find any information concerning input limitations.

My idea is simple (in theory), an input prompt appears:

```
Input symbol coords--
X:_    Y:
```

What I want to do is limit the number of characters to be inputted,
meaning that after entering '5' the output changes to:

```
Input symbol coords--
X:5    Y:_
```

(the `_` indicates the position of cursor)

The main point is for this to happen without the user having to press the return key("enter"). My main stumbling point has been that once a cin.get() or cin statement has been called of it completes before reading any other code(naturally).

```
char x;
char y;
cout << "X: ";
cin.get(x); //conditions to halt after receiving 1 char input
cout << "X: " << x << "  Y: ";
cin.get(y); //conditions to halt after receiving 1 char input
cout << "X: " << x << "  Y: " << y << endl;
```

Question: Is this functionality possible in a **c++ console application**?
If so, how would this be implemented?

Comment: Not using the facilities of Standard C++.

Comment: @NeilButterworth after posting this a friend found a function that essentially does what I was looking for. <conio.h> getch(). prompts then grabs and returns one character(an int value but a char can be assigned to the returned value).

Comment: Yes, as I said, not using the facilities of Standard C++.

Comment: ah, right, I guess i had not considered that <conio.h> was non-standard.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: What about [basic_istream::read](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read)?

Comment: @Andy You would still need to hit return.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a direct answer to my original question but it works as I intended. Key parts: library "conio.h" and the function getch(), which returns the integer value of the key pressed.

```
#include <conio.h>
...
char x;
char y;
cout << "X: ";
x = getch();
cout << x << "  Y: ";
y = getch();
cout << y << endl;
char t; //keeping the console open
cin >> t; //keeping the console open
```

After this, both char variables hold the correct values.

Comment: You should be aware that using a non-standard header like `<conio.h>` makes your program platform-dependent. You should also be aware that it is often wrong to assume that stdin and stdout are related to the keyboard and to the screen. For example, `std::cin` may read from some other program's output, and `std::cout` may write into a file. `./program | other_program >output.txt`

Comment: @ChristianHackl thank you, I did not know this. while these aren't needed to be considered for this small project, I still pays to know.

Answer (score -1):

There is a 'raw mode' for terminal

> In  raw state, the terminal device driver returns one character at a
>   time without assembling lines of data.

Here you can find more info: 
http://www.lafn.org/~dave/linux/terminalIO.html

Here is a similiar question on stackoverflow with the answer:
[Making terminal input send after a certain number of characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186036/making-terminal-input-send-after-a-certain-number-of-characters?rq=1)